# Нужна ли запятая: "Торговый комплекс тянет как магнит"

Tags: пунктуация

Предложение: Торговый комплекс тянет как магнит. Нужна ли запятая перед как, у автора поставлена. И мне не нравится слово "тянет", наверное, лучше "притягивает".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Запятая не нужна, так как тянет *как магнит* можно заменить на *магнитом*.

Лопатин:оборот с *как* не обособляется,

г) если оборот имеет значение образа действия (такие обороты можно заменить творительным падежом существительного или наречием): Мы наступали. Сербы сражались как львы (Кат.) (ср.: по-львиному); Тропинка извивалась как змея (ср.: змеей);

Answer (score 3):

Запятая в данном случае вариативна, т.к. в вашем примере в сравнительном обороте на первый план выступает обстоятельство образа действия (обороты с как можно заменить в этих случаях формой творительного падежа существительного или наречием).

***Торговый комплекс тянет как магнит( магнитом - тв.пад.).*** При анализе таких примеров исходят из авторской пунктуации: если важно создать сравнение, запятая ставится.

***Ср.: Она ускользнёт, как змея, порхнёт и умчится, как птичка,*** мы можем допустить, что в последнем случае автору важно было создать художественные образы путем, так сказать, чистого сравнения ***(подобно змее, подобно птичке, хотя сравнение сохраняется и в сочетаниях ускользнёт змеёй, умчится птичкой, но с добавочным оттенком образа действия).***

См. Справочник по пунктуации. Розенталь. Д. Э.

Глагол ***"тянет"*** также употребляется со словом магнит. Об этом свидетельствует словарная фиксация.

Answer (score 2):

Запятая нужна – это чистый сравнительный оборот. Случай простейший, не надо мудрствовать.

Comment: Грамматика по Niemand. Сравнительные обороты бывают чистые и не совсем чистые. При виде чистого оборота смело обособляйте его.  В простейших случаях не надо мудрствовать.

Comment: А ваши "правильные равновесные конструкции" – это грамматика по Vera? Пунктуация, зависящая от "тонических ударений" – грамматика по Vera?

Answer (score 1):

(1) Торговый комплекс притЯгивает как магнИт. Оборот в качестве обстоятельства входит в основное сообщение (по принципу тема-рема) и не обособляется.

(2) Торговый кОмплекс, как магнИт, всегда притЯгивает меня. Оборот обособляется как попутное сравнение и относится к информации второго плана.

В решении подобных задач очень важна структура предложения и его распространенность, что является решающим фактором в РАССТАНОВКЕ ПАУЗ (ЗАПЯТЫХ) И ТОНИЧЕСКИХ УДАРЕНИЙ.

**Упражнения по замене оборота на сущ. в Т.п. чисто формальны и обычно не дают результата.** Не стоит думать, что в этом случае мы проверяем семантику оборота, она остается неизменной при обособлении и без обособления.

Comment: Вера, не всегда. Ср.: Тянет, притягивает, как магнит . ( Пример из словаря Кузнецова).

Comment: Живу, любуясь безделушками,
А вечность тянет, ***как магнит***,
И пасторальными пастушками
(Как неожиданно! И. В. Чиннов. «Живу, изящными уютами...» Люблю я свежий мрак, всевидящий, но скромный, ―
Соблазном вкрадчивым он тянет, ***как магнит***.(Г. В. Голохвастов). 'Улица

Comment: Серж! Но это же совершенно разные по грамматике и структуре предложения! ТЯнет, притЯгивает, как магнИт.  Очень правильная, равновесная конструкция, не обособить оборот просто нельзя.

Comment: Вера, и в примере автора и в этом примере оборот с как напрямую зависит от глагола.  А вот в вашем примере оборот с как оторван от глагола. Кстати, а как вы объясните постановку запятой в приведенных мной примерах и в примерах Розенталя?

Comment: Другие примеры тоже с другой структурой. Можно обособить оборот в конце предложения, но при этом нужно понимать, что содержание предложения должно быть самодостаточным без оборота и вы можете прочитать предложение, выделив паузой оборот. Надо изменить приведенный пример хотя бы так: " Торговый комплекс всегда  притягивает, как магнит".

Comment: Ср.: «Самарканд притягивает, как магнит». Торговый комплекс тянет как магнит.

Comment: Как здесь объясните? Вера, добавления одного слова еще не дает основания для обособления или обособления оборота.

Comment: Все примеры объяснятся одинаково: расставьте паузы и тонические ударения и прочитайте предложение. Обычно очень трудно обособить  оборот в простом предложении. состоящим из трех слов.

Comment: Запрещенный город притягивает, как магнит.

Comment: Серж, давайте рассуждать философски: равновесие системы может нарушить добавление очень малого элемента (как в сказке про Репку).

Comment: Вера, почему вы не обращаете на одинаковые по структуре примеры? 
 
Запрещенный город притягивает, как магнит. Торговый комплекс тянет как магнит.  В чем тогда разница в этих двух примерах?

Comment: Он умер, как настоящий герой (подобно герою’). — Он умер как настоящий герой (‘умер героем’)

Answer (score 1):

ОТВЕТЫ НА КОММЕНТАРИИ

Торговый комплекс - это попросту магазин, а запрещенный город - это уже информация, семантика со значением уступки, получается почти аналог СПП.

Или тянет - притягивает: количество слогов-то разное, да и значение приставки ПРИ надо учитывать.

Я сейчас читаю книгу известного автора-практика с высоким рейтингом продаж "Как стать писателем" (600 стр.), где утверждается. что выразительность слова  внутри фразы  зависит от числа слогов.

Он умер, как настоящий герой - это аналог СПП с придаточным сравнительным.

КАЖДОЕ ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИЕ УНИКАЛЬНО, а правила призывают к  их уравниловке.

Comment: Вера, при чем тут значение уступки? Где в правилах написано такое? Он умер, как настоящий герой ( в книге как с запятой , так и без).

Comment: Запрещенный, но притягивает - дополнительное обстоятельственное значение.   Далее несколько примеров, для каждого примера  автор может выбрать решение. По смыслу, по стилю, по контексту, каждый раз решение индивидуальное. И вот он умер как художник. Он умер как праведник. Он умер как преступник, он не умер как герой или мученик. Конец его был прекрасен, он умер, как невинный ребенок. В некоторых случаях решение выглядит однозначным, в других возможны авторские варианты. Гарантия правильности решения - это соответствующая семантика, выраженная гармоничной формой.

Comment: И вернемся к примеру.Торговый комплекс тянет как магнит. Вы можете поставить запятую. Семантика будет выражена однозначно, но предложение не читается, нет у фразы нужной "музыкальности",  гладкости. Но, наверное, это не всем понятно.

Comment: И еще один пример. Он умер как герой (геройски) Он умер, как настоящий герой.  Теперь вряд ли  "по- настоящему геройски" можно считать обстоятельством. Это содержание более соответствует обособленному обороту.

Comment: Вера, в том-то и дело, в некоторых вариантах ( в примере автора в том числе) возможна авторская пунктуация. В чем и заключается весь спор.  Об этом и пишет Розенталь.

Comment: Я сегодня просмотрела Нацкорпус по этой теме и пришла к выводу, что очень много зависит от контекста. Одинаковые по структуре предложения в разном окружении решаются по-разному, но без особой вариативности. Каждый текст задает свою ритмику, и предложение должно однозначно вписываться в нее.

Comment: Вера, примеры я как раз-таки брал оттуда. У Розенталя сказано: если на первый план выходит сравнение, запятая ставится, если об-ство - запятой нет.